# Dell vostro 3700 and windows server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dell-vostro

I have a Dell vostro 3700 which had  win7 on it.  I installed windows server 2008 R2, but it does not recognise all hardware and as a result it operates at a very low screen resolution.

How do I properly install the drivers for the graphics?

Answer (score 0):

There are no W2K8R2 specific drivers on the Dell site for that model, in fact that OS isn't listed as being supported on that model - you may well be out of luck, maybe next time check that the server you're buying supports the OS you want.